# image in CALayer is not scaled down properly and has anti-aliasing issues

Tags: macos, cocoa, calayer

I am learning about `CALayer` and have the following problem. The following two images

[image]

are in fact two views in my app: the one on the left is an `NSImageView` and the one on the right is a layer-hosting `NSView` with the same image as contents. Here is the code for the `ViewController` that I used to set this up:

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
  @IBOutlet weak var aView: NSView!
  @IBOutlet weak var anImage: NSImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()

      let img = NSImage(named: "emptyStar")!

      let l = CALayer()
      l.contents = img

      aView.layer = l
      aView.wantsLayer = true

      anImage.image = img
  }
}
```

Why does the `CALayer` image look so bad and how can I fix this (sticking with `CALayer`)? A magnification of the right image shows bad anti-aliasing.

Things I tried are: 1) generating a `CGImage` using

```
   img.CGImageForProposedRect(&aView.frame, context: nil, hints: [NSImageHintInterpolation: 3])
```

and setting this as contents of `l`, 2) setting `l.contentsScale=2`, 3) setting `l.edgeAntialiasingMask=[.LayerLeftEdge, .LayerRightEdge, .LayerBottomEdge, .LayerTopEdge]`, 4) making `aView` layer-backed, by moving `aView.wantsLayer=true` before `aView.layer = l`. I could not make any of those work...

Both views are 50 x 50 while the image itself is a 253 x 254 PNG image that I grabbed from this tutorial

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/

and it is in the Assets for this app.

I am pretty sure I am missing something simple here...

Thanks for any help!

UPDATE: 
Delegating the drawing seems to work:

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var aView: NSView!

    override func drawLayer(layer: CALayer, inContext ctx: CGContext) {
        NSGraphicsContext.setCurrentContext(NSGraphicsContext(CGContext: ctx, flipped: false))
        NSImage(named: "emptyStar")!.drawInRect(layer.bounds)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let l = CALayer()
        l.delegate = self

        aView.layer = l
        aView.wantsLayer = true

        aView.layer!.setNeedsDisplay()
   }

}
```

Hopefully there is a better solution to something that should work off the box...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll get aliasing artifacts if you don't use the correct min/mag filters.

Since you're putting a larger image into a smaller CALayer, you'd want to use linear, bilinear or trilinear filtering (in increasing order of cost).

For a layer, you can set the min filter using:

```
layer.minificationFilter = kCAFilterTrilinear;
```

Comment: Cool! This works. I was fiddling with AutoLayout and auto-resizing my layer and this seems to work there too. Although, your comment for cost and the documentation on this make me a little nervous about using it... Out of curiosity (if you know): is this what Cocoa does for rendering NSImage "by default"? if so, why did not they make this CALayer's default as well...

Comment: This is all done on the GPU, so I wouldn't worry too much about the cost. Afaik, you can expect linear to be 2x, bilinear to be 4x and trilinear to be 12x the cost of not doing any interpolation. Not too sure what NSImage uses by default, but I do know they generate several image representations for different sizes. You could potentially check the values of imageInterpolation on NSGraphicsContext to find out.